# how to retrieve value of column in editTable

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add autocomplete to one of the columns of edittable.

```
// Initialize table example 3
itinerarytable = $("#maintable").editTable({
data: [
    ["",""],
],
headerCols: [
    'Client Name',
        'Itinerary Id', 
]
//maxRows: 3
});

$("#maintable").on("focusin", "td:nth-child(1) input", function(){
    $(this).autocomplete({ 
            source: function (request, response) {
            var username = $(this).get(name);
            alert(username);
            $.get('autocompleteServlet', {user : username},function(responseText){
                var obj = $.parseJSON(responseText); 
                response(obj);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

but always getting empty or undefined for username
Now my question is how can I access value by username

Comment: We're going to need some markup to verify your JavaScript. Also, you get a babillion imaginary points if you create a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: There is a mistake in your autocomplete code..verify that..check this fiddle it works fine with default autocomplete http://jsfiddle.net/N73w2/

show your servlet